# Why tr in table adds additional height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to figure out why the 2 rows are so far apart, since there is no additional height on the inner tables. Inspecting the height in Chrome shows that the topmost TD has 50px, while the table underneath is 24px.

Why is this the case?

```html
<table width="540px" height="94px" style="background-color: #fafbfc;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0 0 0 55px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <table style="border-collapse:separate;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <span style="display:block;padding:0px 15px;">First field</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span style="text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:0px 15px;">Second field</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0 55px 0 55px; vertical-align:middle;">
        another
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `cellpadding` and `cellspacing`.
According to this [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-cellpadding-and-cellspacing/) article

**Cellpadding** specifies the space between the border of a table cell and its contents (i.e) it defines the whitespace between the cell edge and the content of the cell.

**Cellspacing** specifies the space between cells (i.e) it defines the whitespace between the edges of the adjacent cells.

If you want both `td` to have same height, then provide `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` attributes to both outer and inner table tags.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ultimately the `width` and `height` attributes you have added.
If you wish to have these, they should go within the `style` attribute

I have taken out most of the styling just for ease of the snippet.

I would also recommend making use of the `thead` and `<th>` elements. As they relate sole to headings in tables. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

```html
<table style="background-color: #fafbfc;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span style="display:block;padding:0px 15px;">First field</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span style="text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:0px 15px;">Second field</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0 55px 0 55px; vertical-align:middle;">
        1st column data
      </td>
      <td style="padding:0 55px 0 55px; vertical-align:middle;">
        More data
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Nesting a table inside another table is not a good idea, that is why you have an unexpected result. When there's table nested inside another table, you may start to get unwanted styles. This is because parent table styles will also affect the child table. For example, if you add height on the parent table, it will affect the child table too.

```html
<table>
    ...
    <table>
      ....
    </table>
</table>
```

Comment: please explain why

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).